# Method for a custom back button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS app for iPhone using Objective C in Xcode. I have a custom toolbar and a custom back button.

If I use

```
[self.na vigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then the button does not do the back action and go back to the previous screen.

How do I navigate to the previous screen if I click the custom back button?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're really asking for. Can you please be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. What have you already tried?

Comment: I think he is asking how to change the back button icon in ios

Comment: @Neoh, you might be right but that is not even sort of the first thing that came to my mind when I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have already add selector to your button.

Then check event of the button, event should be 'touchUpInside'.

These are the most common mistakes.